# How to do search-and-replace in a macro?

Tags: macros

Is it possible to let (La)TeX search and replace text in a macro during compile time? For example, given

```
\newcommand{\sometext}{a b c d e f g}
```

I'd like to have something like

```
\searchreplace{\sometext}{b c}{x

y}
```

that would result in

```
a x

y d e f g
```

Ideally this would work with replacing macros, like

```
\searchreplace{hi {\itshape there}}{\itshape}{\bfseries}
```

that then would produce (and interpret)

```
hi {\bfseries there}
```

Comment: First, I know that this is only an example, but please do not ever use `\bf` or `\it` in LaTeX---use `\bfseries` and `\itshape`. Second, do you mean something like what the package `xpatch` does? http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch

Comment: There seems little benefit when supplying something verbatim that requires a change; the question there would be "Why not just change whatever you want right there...?". It's more likely you'd like to search-and-replace inside something "unknown" like a macro. That's a major difference between your first and second examples.

Comment: yo - I changed the example. Maybe I tried to make it too short :)

Comment: Werner - The original macro is sourced from another file I do not have under control, and that needs minimal tweaks when used in multiple other files. Otherwise I would have asked my text editor to do the job :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides exactly this functionality via `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}`, where it searches for `<search>` in `<cmd>` and replaces it with `<replace>`, executing `<success>` if the search-and-replace was successful, otherwise `<failure>`.

The following uses an elementary parameter passing to `\patchcmd`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\searchreplace}[3]{\patchcmd{#1}{#2}{#3}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sometext}{a b c d e f g}

\sometext

\searchreplace{\sometext}{b c}{x

y}

\sometext

\end{document}
```

It would be advisable to also include `\tracingpatches` in order to make sure (via the `.log`) what went wrong if a patch wasn't successful.

You may run into problems with certain macros, for which your go-to alternative would be [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch). Of course, other options also exist (using, for example, [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch)).