# Find and replace text in bibentry using macros

Tags: macros, bibentry

I want to be able to display a bibliography entry but I want to highlight some part of it, specifically some author, but not all. So far I am able to create the bib entry in the middle of the text, and I am also able to do a find and replace of text (copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263848/how-to-do-search-and-replace-in-a-macro)). However, when I try to do the find and replace the text of the bib entry it does not work.

Here is my example bib tex file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
{

@InProceedings{pcl,
  author    = {Radu Bogdan Rusu and Steve Cousins},
  title     = {{3D is here: Point Cloud Library (PCL)}},
  booktitle = {{IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA)}},
  month     = {May 9-13},
  year      = {2011},
  address   = {Shanghai, China}
  }
@misc{opencv,
  title={Open Source Computer Vision Library},
  author={Itseez},
  year={2015},
  howpublished = {\url{https://github.com/itseez/opencv}}
  }
@manual{opencv_manual,
  title = {The OpenCV Reference Manual},
  organization = {Itseez},
  edition = {2.4.9.0},
  month = {April},
  year = {2014},
  notes = {See \url{http://opencv.org/}}
  }
}

\end{filecontents}   

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\nobibliography*

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\newcommand{\searchreplace}[3]{\patchcmd{#1}{#2}{#3}{}{}}
\newcommand{\bibelement}[1]
{
    \begin{NoHyper}% In my real project I need the bibentry package to work with hyperref package.
        \bibentry{#1}
    \end{NoHyper}
} 
\newcommand{\bibelementhighlight}[2]
{
    %\searchreplace{\bibelement{#1}}{#2}{\textbf{#2}}
    \newcommand{\auxbibliography}{\bibelement{#1}}
    First time: \auxbibliography \\
    \searchreplace{\auxbibliography}{#2}{\textbf{#2}}
    Second time: \auxbibliography
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\afgfgft}{Rusu, R. B. and Cousins, S.}
\afgfgft \\
\searchreplace{\afgfgft}{Rusu, R. B.}{\textbf{Rusu, R. B.}}
\afgfgft

Here are some citations for articles: \cite{pcl} and \cite{opencv} and \bibelement{opencv_manual} and the one which I want to highlight:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \bibelementhighlight{pcl}{Rusu}
\end{itemize}


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this code I get the following (note that there is also added drawing and text explaining what I want to get): 
[image]

where everything works fine except for the substitution of `Rusu` the second time the bibelement is displayed. After messing arround I think that this might be because `\bibitem` is expanded after the string replace. Can somebody give me a hint on how to solve it?

Comment: I cannot get your MWE to compile.  It says there is a runaway argument.

Comment: I can compile this exact same code with [sharelatex](www.sharelatex.com) and in my computer using Ubungu 14.04 by doing pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex. I do not know what your error is...